# html form value to mysql database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I've made a basic html page to send email value to mysql using nodejs, but it doesn't work, i see no errors when i run it on cmd node test.js and i see no errors on my localhost cmd.

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> email lol </title>
    <script src= "test.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="userEmail" type = "email" > </input>
    <input type = "submit" onclick="sendEmail();"> </input>
</body>
</html>
```

My nodejs

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "Bionicle123!",
    database: "account"
});

con.connect(function(err)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});

function sendEmail()
{
    var gebruikerEmail = document.getElementById("userEmail").value;
    var sqlGebruikerEmail = "INSERT INTO persoon (email) VALUES (gebruikerEmail)";

    con.query(sqlGebruikerEmail, function (err, result)
    {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
}
```

Comment: are you seeing any console.log value?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at test.js:1

Comment: are you using require js?

Comment: nope, how do i do that?

Comment: check this https://requirejs.org/

Comment: not working, i need to know whats wrong in my code

Comment: require is not supported in the browser as it is nodejs function.
You have to use Browserify to make require work in the browser.